# Parsing Reddit RSS feed - PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to get the title and link of an rss feed -

```
https://www.reddit.com/r/gif.rss
```

(the reddit feed)

```
xml=simplexml_load_file("https://www.reddit.com/r/gif.rss") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

foreach ($xml->entry->content as $x) {
$title = $x->title;
$string = $x->link;
echo $title;
echo "<br>";
echo $string;
}
```

I can't get title or link to appear.

Comment: I don't see any echo statements

Comment: I tried echoing title and string - nothing happens

Comment: `$x` is a string object, which you can echo. You'll have to parse the html from `$x`.

Answer (score 2):

Sorted it out:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("https://www.reddit.com/r/gif.rss") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

function extractString($string, $start, $end) {
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}


foreach ($xml->entry as $x) {
$string = $x->content;

$url =  extractString($string, '<span><a href="', '">[link]</a></span>');
$title = extractString($string, 'alt="', '" title');
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply adjust your path expression. The `<content>` node does not contain `<title>` or `<link>` children though their content is contained in content's text value. Instead, the nodes you need are siblings, so remove `<content>` in loop path:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("https://www.reddit.com/r/gif.rss") 
                              or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach ($xml->entry as $x) {
    $title = $x->title;
    $string = $x->link['href'];
    echo $title;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $string;
}

// This guy loves his job
// <br>
// https://www.reddit.com/r/gif/comments/53i3jc/this_guy_loves_his_job/
// Letron BMW E92 Transformer
// <br>
// https://www.reddit.com/r/gif/comments/53i13r/letron_bmw_e92_transformer/
// MRW "you're cute when you're angry"
// <br>
// https://www.reddit.com/r/gif/comments/53ihpf /mrw_youre_cute_when_youre_angry/
// Pussy Pass Denied
// <br>
// https://www.reddit.com/r/gif/comments/53hm3w/pussy_pass_denied/
// My favorite reverse gif so far
// <br>
// https://www.reddit.com/r/gif/comments/53ihwr/my_favorite_reverse_gif_so_far/
// Oh hooman, you will hug me. --Dog
// <br>
// https://www.reddit.com/r/gif/comments/53cbcq/oh_hooman_you_will_hug_me_dog/
...
```